# SharePoint 2013 pages library is no longer inheriting the master page layout from the top level subsite

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, sub-site, inheritance, pages

I have a problem on a SharePoint 2013 subsite which uses a custom master page template, all sitepages and libraries used to inherit this layout, however now we've noticed that the pages library is no longer inheriting the master layout whereas all child site sitepages do. e.g. http://sitecollection/subsite/Pages/pagename.aspx are no longer inheriting the master layout yet http://sitecol/subsite/childsite/SitePages/Home.aspx are still inheriting the master layout.

I'm not sure why this has changed, but it was only noticed in the week after applying the August Windows Updates to the servers in the farm. We are running SharePoint 2013 enterprise.

The master page was configured using SharePoint designer and the changesitemasterpage settings on the top level subsite have "inherit site master from parent site" enabled and "Specify a system master page" enabled but the template selected is different to what is in SharePoint designer. As it was explained to me that because the subsite designers (for this particular subsite) don't have full permissions and aren't part of the designers group (they only contribute access to the site collection masterpage gallery) in order to have a custom design they had to use site publishing and designer to edit and assign the default master page for their subsite. Also any other library be it document or list etc... is getting the custom layout but not the pages library.

My Questions are:

- Do pages libraries automatically inherit the layout from the top
  level subsite or is this supposed to be configured, and where?
- What can I do to fix this so that all pages and sitepages on this
  subsite continue to inherit the layout from the top level subsite?